# Technology to separate storage from business logic (RDBMS & NoSQL)

Tags: php, database, pdo, doctrine-orm, orm

Is there currently any technology that would separate storage from business logic *and* allow me, to easily switch from MySQL do MongoDB? (I assume I migrate the data myself, or start with an empty database after the switch).

I would like the change to be as easy as changing the configuration, the driver, and the db connection data.

I understand it is possible for PHP with Doctrine, switching between different RDBMS, but I'm interested in switching from any RDBMS to a NoSQL system.

I am focusing on PHP now - but if you know any solutions for other programming languages - I will be happy to learn about them.

I am assuming not a complex database, no transactions, no complex relations.

#### More background/details

I am writing a simple crawler that will visit websites, and read some data and save it to the DB. It is super simple and I might go with pdo_mysql for PHP only. I am considering an extra layer *only* to cover the situation in case I want to switch from MySQL to MongoDB one day - and I asking if this is even possible.

#### Update

I think that Laravel with its Eloquent supports MySQL out of the box, and with an extra plugin: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb supports MongoDB - I will check if this is truly transparent from the programmer's perspective. Unless someone has experience and knows right away?

Comment: The abstraction layer required to accommodate two so vastly and fundamentally different DMBSes will be quite thick. Like... an entire application thick. Or more.

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach here is the DAO or Repository design pattern.  In this pattern you provide a library which is responsible for persistence and returns business objects.  The objects do not have persistence logic and get stashed in the Repository or retrieved from the repository.

This being said, that only works for business objects.  The problems will come up when you want to redo reporting or the like....  Here the differences between an RDBMS and a NoSQL solution will bite you hard.

To be sure I don't know what a use case is given that "what do you want to do with your data" is a massive concern in selecting between these.

Comment: After doing some research I see that Eloquent from Laravel (supports Mysql) and can support MongoDB with an extra plugin: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb